# Trying to access information from a nsdictionary created by json

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to access information in an nsdictionary created from a json and can't seem to figure out how to access the values. I've gotten the dictionary to print it out but can't access the specific keys/values: here is the json

[
    {
  "id": "1",
  "question": "how old are you",
  "answers": [
              "7",
              "9",
              "13"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "2",
  "question": "how old are you",
  "answers": [
              "7",
              "9",
              "13"
              ]
  }
]

My biggest confusion is the format that I get when I log out the dictionary:

NSLog(@"%@", questionsAndAnswers);

I get back:

( {
answers =         (
            7,
            9,
            13
        );
        id = 1;
        question = "how old are you";
    },
        {
        answers =         (
            7,
            9,
            13
        );
        id = 2;
        question = "how old are you";
}
)

so the display order is different from the input order which I suppose isn't a big deal. I want to do something like:

```
NSArray  *answersArray = [questionsAndAnswers allKeysForObject:@"answers"];
```

Which I kind of learned from here :http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html

But I get errors with no matter how I've been formatting it.

Here is the code for the dictionary:

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataJson" ofType:@"json"];

NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];

questionsAndAnswers = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated!
keep in mind I am a novice ios developer.. also I researched this for a few hours now to no avail

Comment: The first thing to understand is that your JSON is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: You also need to better explain your problem. Show what you have tried. Explain what you are trying to get and what you actually get.

Comment: I'll edit and explain more thanks!

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes, and being able to read JSON makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Then understand that an array is bracketed by `[]` in JSON but by `()` in an NSArray dump.  A JSON "object" (NSDictionary) is bracketed by `{}` in both views.  And note that the order of name/value pairs in a JSON "object" is never guaranteed to be preserved.

Comment: And when you get `[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` it means that the thing you thought was a dictionary is really an array.

Answer (score 0):

`questionsAndAnswers` will be an **array of dictionaries**. so you can access the id of the first question by: `questionsAndAnswers[0]["id"]`

The id of the second question will be `questionsAndAnswers[1][@"id"]` and so on.

Comment: I did not realize it was an array of dictionaries. I thought it might be something like that but since that is confirmed I can learn more about handling array of dictionaries. Thank you